# Error when importingPython-vlc

Tags: python, windows, vlc, python-3.6

I have installed python-vlc

`D:\Programing\Python\Python 3.6>python -m pip install python-vlc
Requirement already satisfied: python-vlc in d:\programing\python\python 3.6\lib\site-packages\python_vlc-1.1.2-py3.6.egg`

When I import the module in idle I get this error

```
>>> import vlc
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
  import vlc
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 646, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 616, in _load_backward_compatible
File "D:\Programing\Python\Python 3.6\lib\site-packages\python_vlc-1.1.2-py3.6.egg\vlc.py", line 181, in <module>
dll, plugin_path  = find_lib()
File "D:\Programing\Python\Python 3.6\lib\site-packages\python_vlc-1.1.2-py3.6.egg\vlc.py", line 156, in find_lib
dll = ctypes.CDLL(libname)
File "D:\Programing\Python\Python 3.6\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 344, in __init__
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

I am running Python 3.6.0 in windows 10 64x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have 64bit python, you need 64bit vlc player. If you have 32bit python, you need 32bit vlc version.

Comment: how do you install 64 bit vlc player

Answer (score 0):

Try the command "pip install vlc" in the CMD.  If that doesn't work, then try "pip install python-vlc"

Comment: I get this error:

`
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement vlc (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for vlc`

Comment: If you have 64bit python, you need 64bit vlc player. If you have 32bit python, you need 32bit vlc player.

Comment: That fixed it thanks, I was running the 32 bit version of vlc on my 64 bit machine. I uninstalled it and installed the 64 bit version.

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: I'm going to post the answer as a new answer so people with the same problem can find it easier.  Please mark it as fixing your problem.